# Looping over an array of sound elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to accomplish a loop that goes over an array of sounds and the idea is to play the sounds one by one.
I tried to make a forEach and tried to set setTimeOut in a for loop and in a forEach but it didnt work out for me.
Any idea how i can get this done?

So, the idea is to go over the array "result" and play the sounds that it contains one by one.(right now when i using a for loop / forEach im getting all the sounds at once.)

My code:

```
// getting the files - buttons
const buttonYel = document.getElementById("btnYellow")
const buttonGre = document.getElementById("btnGreen")
const buttonBlue = document.getElementById("btnBlue")
const buttonRed = document.getElementById("btnRed")
const button = document.querySelector("button")
// getting the files - sounds
const soundRed = document.getElementById("soundRed")
const soundYel = document.getElementById("soundYellow")
const soundBlue = document.getElementById("soundBlue")
const soundGre = document.getElementById("soundGreen")

let result = [];
let userResult = [];
let currectPickComp;
let currectPickUser;

button.addEventListener("click", gameStart)
function gameStart() {


setTimeout(()=> {
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()* 4) + 1;
if (random === 1){
    result.push(soundYel)
    soundYel.play();
    buttonYel.style.animation = "shake 0.5s";
    currectPickComp = soundYel;
} else if (random === 2){
    result.push(soundRed);
    soundRed.play();  
    buttonRed.style.animation = "shake 0.5s"; 
    currectPickComp = soundRed;
} else if (random === 3){
    result.push(soundBlue)
    soundBlue.play();
    buttonBlue.style.animation = "shake 0.5s";  
    currectPickComp = soundBlue; 
} else if (random === 4){
    result.push(soundGre);
    soundGre.play()   
    buttonGre.style.animation = "shake 0.5s";
    currectPickComp = soundGre;  
}}, 500)}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a simple [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will do. Just have it run at 500ms and make it pick a sound like you're already doing.

Comment: I tried something like that, any chance for example? i might have missed something in the process

Comment: @icecub's suggestion is good but for future reference you can get the `forEach` to work if you set the timeout to be the (timeout * the index).  E.g. `array.forEach((val, index) => { // something }, index * 500);`

Comment: In the above code, create a global variable `let soundTimer;`. Then inside your `gameStart()` function change `setTimeout(()` to `soundTimer = setInterval(()`. Then when the game stops, just use `clearInterval(soundTimer);` to have it stop.

Comment: The only difference between `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` is that the timeout only runs once, while the interval keeps on running forever untill canceled. Aside from that, they work exactly the same.

Comment: @StevenB. That has a few downsides. It wouldn't pick a random sound (like in the code given by OP) and it would only loop through the array once if I'm not mistaken. Not to mention that `forEach()` can't be canceled (unless you throw an exception).

Comment: @icecub Oh I agree and you're correct. I was just giving it for reference since he mentioned when he used a loop with setTimeout they all played at once.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!